# How to call object's method from constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop

var Dog = function(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.sayName();
    }

```
Dog.prototype.sayName = function() {
  alert(this.name);
}
```

I'm creating new instance of Dog object `Dog('Bowwow')`, but method sayName() is undefined. Why?

Or maybe I should do something like (but I can't see difference)...

```
var Dog = function(name) {

  this.name = name;

  this.sayName();

  this.prototype.sayName = function() {
    alert(this.name);
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your first code sample works great. What problem are you experiencing? You can see it working here: http://jsbin.com/uxevi3

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert, see eBusiness answer. I've just forget to use new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript is a little dodgy in this area, your code works as long as you call Dog using the `new` constructor.

```
new Dog("Hello world")
```

The new constructor makes `this` behave like you want it to. Otherwise it is totally different.